# Как написать бота в телеграмм?

Tags: python

Как написать бота в телеграмм?

Я не хочу подробных пошаговых инструкций о том как написать бота для телеграмма.
Просто по запросу в гугле - "Что изучать чтобы написать бота телеграм..."
"Что учить чтобы написать бота телеграм?..." и тд (я конечно утрирую, но все же..) выходят ссылки на всякие курсы за миллионы денег, у меня тх нет, просто укажите какую стезю изучать, чтобы в целом уметь писать автоматизированные программы по типу телеграм бота или бота для любых других целей, я знаю лишь язык питон на уровне не дальше функций, и что вообще ..............................
делать

Comment: вообще  - не писать подобных вопросов на этом сайте - вот что делать.

Comment: Хоть комментатор сверху и написал комментарий в недружелюбной манере, но он прав, такие вопросы и вправду не стоит задавать, т.к. они не соответствуют правилам сайта. Я бы вам посоветовал ещё подучить Python, узнать о массивы/объекты, как работать с аргументами, декораторах, классах, методах, стандартные библиотеки (по типу `math`, `requests` и тд.), о том как писать чистый код, возможно ещё про асинхронный код. Далее уже выбрать их библиотек по типу AIOGram, pyTelegramBotAPI или других. Дальше, учите её базу и пишите бота. По ходу обучения вы лучше узнаете как работать с APIшкой тг для бота.

Answer (score 1):

Ну для простеньких ботов хватит и знаний до функций, но в общем советую изучать питон дальше до классов и т.д., помимо этого изучай sql(изучи как писать простые запросы и создавать и взаимодействовать с таблицами),  изучи библиотеку для создания бота(советую aiogram). Практиковаться и продолжать изучать и тогда у тебя обязательно получится что-то годное! В общем того что я сказал хватит для старта, дальше думаю по пути поймешь сам что тебе нужно, по типу api и т.д.

Comment: спасибо                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ........